# Rest/Odata $Filter not working on certain keys

Tags: c#, rest, sharepoint, filter, odata

I am trying to query some information from a SharePoint list. Now, I am trying to use odata to get it. my problem is that for some reason, $filter is not working with all my keys in that list :S. Here is an example:

*This works OK*:

1. ...ccm/_api/Lists/GetByTitle('Circuit%20Deliveries')/Items?$filter=**Title** eq 'AUG'

*But this one doesn't work (HTTP 400 bad request)*

2. ...ccm/_api/Lists/GetByTitle('Circuit%20Deliveries')/Items?$filter=**Delivery_x0020_Date** eq null

Nevertheless, the field name is OK, since I am able to use select and orderby with the same field name. Here is the XML output in IE for 2 'Titles' named AUG:

> ...ccm/_api/Lists/GetByTitle('Circuit%20Deliveries')/Items?$filter=Title
>   eq
>   'AUG'&$select=Title,Delivery_x0020_Date,Status_x0020__x002d__x0020_Calcu

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> -
<feed xml:base="/ccm/_api/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss"
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
  <id>5a2630a8-c00a-4baa-bd43-3912d9264df8</id>
  <title />
  <updated>2017-09-08T10:58:12Z</updated>
  <entry m:etag="" 33 "">
    <id>Web/Lists(guid'5ad8ca39-191a-4586-bdef-7bc4830eced9')/Items(332)</id>
    <category term="SP.Data.Circuit_x0020_DeliveriesListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'5ad8ca39-191a-4586-bdef-7bc4830eced9')/Items(332)" />
    <title />
    <updated>2017-09-08T10:58:12Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Title>AUG</d:Title>
        <d:Delivery_x0020_Date m:type="Edm.DateTime">2017-03-06T06:00:00Z</d:Delivery_x0020_Date>
        <d:Status_x0020__x002d__x0020_Calcu>Circuit Ready for Production Use on 03/06/2017</d:Status_x0020__x002d__x0020_Calcu>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry m:etag="" 58 "">
    <id>Web/Lists(guid'5ad8ca39-191a-4586-bdef-7bc4830eced9')/Items(333)</id>
    <category term="SP.Data.Circuit_x0020_DeliveriesListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'5ad8ca39-191a-4586-bdef-7bc4830eced9')/Items(333)" />
    <title />
    <updated>2017-09-08T10:58:12Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Title>AUG</d:Title>
        <d:Delivery_x0020_Date m:null="true" />
        <d:Status_x0020__x002d__x0020_Calcu>Site Survey completed on 09/09/2016</d:Status_x0020__x002d__x0020_Calcu>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

As you can see I was able to successfully query and select both fields from the list and filter by Title. Nevertheless, I would like to further filter on Delivery_x0020_Date being empty (or null).

I searched around and some people were saying that filtering by null on dates is not always working. But in my case is a bit more than that, because even if I try to filter by another key(Status_x0020__x002d__x0020_Calcu) it will return *Bad Request*

Is there a requirement on what type of keys you can filter on?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**REST API in SharePoint 2013 does Not support null values for filtering on list item queries.** (Refer this [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f20cb779-825f-4261-9623-26551fe5c853/how-to-filter-on-null-dates-via-rest-api?forum=appsforsharepoint) link)

You will have to find some other workaround.

however, We can combine the CAML query with REST API to get the required data in Javascript object model. Refer this link - [REST API to filter on null](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/201472/sharepoint-rest-api-filter-empty-lookup-field/201483#201483).

But I am not sure about the c# code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in my case is not about null values. Take this as an example:

`...ccm/_api/Lists/GetByTitle('Circuit%20Deliveries')/Items?$filter=substringof('Circuit Ready for Production Use on', Status_x0020__x002d__x0020_Calcu)`

This also returns bad request :S